# RichtextString notworking in hssfworkbook cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to color my excel sheet cell text partially so i m using richtextstring for this but it is not working ... there is no error.i am unable to figureout whats wrong.
Here is my code.

In this answer is the string.. i want to color the string till last (,) in red and remaining in black

```
    if (answer.contains(",")) {

                                String s = ",";

                                int second = answer.lastIndexOf(s);


                                HSSFCell cell7 = thisRow.createCell((short) i);
                                cell7.setCellStyle(style2);
                                HSSFRichTextString richTextString = new HSSFRichTextString(
                                        answer);
                                richTextString.applyFont(0, second, style5.getFontIndex());

                                cell7.setCellValue("" + richTextString);

When i try to use                               cell7.setCellValue(richTextString);
it says : 
The method setCellValue(String) in the type HSSFCell is not applicable for the arguments (HSSFRichTextString)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are accidentally converting the `RichTextString` back to a `String` by concatenating it with an empty string `""`.  That effectively removes all formatting.

Don't concatenate with `""`, because there is an overloaded [`setCellValue` method that takes a `RichTextString`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString)) directly.

```
cell7.setValue(richTextString);
```

Comment: cell7.setValue(richTextString); is not taking richtextstring thats why i have concatenate with ""